# v8 on a background thread in Android JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, v8, libv8

I am trying to call v8 from a JNI call in an android application from a background thread. It is causing a runtime crash with a complaint about v8::ObjectTemplate::New(v8::Handle

to reproduce call the following jni

```
    void JSfunc() {
        v8::Isolate* currentIsolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
        if(!currentIsolate) {
            currentIsolate = v8::Isolate::New();
        }
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(currentIsolate);
        v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New();
    }
```

from the following Java code

```
    {
    final Thread loadJS = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JSfunc());
        }
    };
    loadJS.start();
    }
```

If you call the function directly from the UI thread or a runnable it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're crashing there, I guess we're right to assume that in the jni code snippet you've left out the long JNI header declaration of JSFunc for our benefit? (Don't blame you...)

Comment: yes i missed out the   extern "C" { JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_app_class_JSfunc( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz ) { JSfunc(); } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code to generate an Isolate is missing

```
currentIsolate->Enter();
```

so the correct JNI function is

```
void JSfunc() {
    v8::Isolate* currentIsolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
    if(!currentIsolate) {
        currentIsolate = v8::Isolate::New();
        currentIsolate->Enter();
    }
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(currentIsolate);
    v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New();
}
```